# Why does a Panel render its child components although its paint method is overridden?

Tags: java, awt

For all I know, the `paint` method of a `Panel` is responsible for rendering the whole `Panel` on screen. So if I "delete" its `paint` method, nothing should be rendered at all. However, in the following simple example, the `Panel` renders its `Button` although I overrode its `paint` method. Why does this happen? Where is the `Button` rendered?

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.Button;
import java.awt.Graphics;

public class SimplePanel extends Applet {
  public SimplePanel() {
    add(new Button("Button"));
  }
  public void paint(Graphics g) {
    // paint nothing at all
  }
}
```

Comment: OP - if you are asking about AWT behaviour, don't tag your questions with Swing.  It is misleading.

Answer (score 0):

In Swing, a component can be painted without effecting its parent, this is done because it's more efficient.

The repaint manager makes decisions about what needs to actually be repainted, optimisimes the process by painting only those components, and where possible, only those parts of the component that need to be painted

Consider taking a look at [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) for more details about how painting works in Swing

The are also some differences in how AWT components and Swing components are painted

Comment: As the posted example uses plain AWT, your answer isn’t really applicable to it. Besides, we can make the above paint method a bit more complicated: Instead of doing nothing, we can draw a line (but nothing more). Then, this line is rendered and also the Button is painted. But this time, the method was obviously called.

Comment: Then why tag it as Swing?  In fact AWT painting is much more simpler, each AWT component is it's own native component/peer, responsible for painting itself, independently of the parent. Check the provided link

Comment: I thought it would be a question independent of AWT and Swing. At least, we can build an almost identical example with Swing instead of AWT which shows exactly the same behavior.

Comment: Actually, in Swing, I can build an example which will give you the expected results, because Swing's painting requirements are different from AWT's

Comment: I don't see how the linked article answers my question. It says there: "Extensions of java.awt.Container which override paint() should always invoke super.paint() to ensure children are painted." But that's exactly what I don't do. I clear the paint method completely and expect that nothing of the panel is rendered. However, the opposite happens.

Comment: If you look through the code for `paint`, you will get to the `Container#paint` method, which actually does very little..actually, nothing at all, apart from setting up a call to the lightweight components, so it's not actually painting any of it's children at all

Comment: Okay, let's forget about child components. Simply replace in the example the line `add(new Button("Button"));` with `setBackground(Color.black);`. We still override the paint method with an empty method. So we have simply a panel without any child components. If we execute the program, we get a black panel, although we instruct the panel to paint nothing. Who paints this black background? Sorry for being "stubborn", but I still haven't understood this whole mechanism.

Comment: In AWT, `update` is used to paint the background color of the component, which the calls paint